# How to make REST API call on Google Cloud

Tags: firebase, rest, authentication, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I am going to use Google FireStore, which doesn't yet have robust client SDKs (like for Node.js). So I am resorting to using the low-level [REST API (or RPC API)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/reference/rpc/google.firestore.admin.v1) directly.

What I'm wondering here is how to make use of the [Service Account Key](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-account-keys), which looks like this:

```
{
  "type": "service_account",
  "project_id": "project-id",
  "private_key_id": "key-id",
  "private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\nprivate-key\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n",
  "client_email": "service-account-email",
  "client_id": "client-id",
  "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
  "token_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token",
  "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
  "client_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/service-account-email"
}
```

When you use the Node.js SDK for example, you just specify:

```
export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="path/to/secrets.json"
```

and somehow the SDK makes use of this information (theoretically, when they are making API requests.

However, when I [search the Node.js SDK source code on GitHub](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-datastore/search?q=private_key&unscoped_q=private_key), I don't see anything. So I don't see how this is used. If I could just see the source code for where they are reading this [`secrets.json`](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-account-keys) I would know how to make the REST API call correctly.

What I would like to know is, how can I manually make a REST API or RPC API request using this secrets.json? Where do I plugin what value? What do I do with each value?

Thank you for your help.

Hmm... maybe I should be looking [here](https://github.com/googleapis/google-auth-library-nodejs).

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't have robust client SDKs"?  Every major web and mobile client platform has an SDK through Firebase.

Comment: Is Firebase the same thing as Firestore?

Comment: No.  Firestore is a massively scalable, cloud-hosted, realtime, nosql database - a product of Google Cloud Platform.  Firebase is a mobile application development platform that shares some of its core products with the Google Cloud ecosystem, including Firestore.  The Firebase SDKs for Firestore provide direct access to Firestore to web and mobile applications.  Most people who use Firestore are actually also using the Firebase platform to build their apps.  It's worth looking into.